# Python Regex find all matches after specific word

Tags: python

I have a string as below
`"Server:  myserver.mysite.com\r\nAddress:  111.122.133.144\r\n\r\nName:    myserver.mysite.com\r\nAddress:  123.144.412.111\r\nAliases:  alias1.myserver.mysite.com\r\n\t  myserver.mysite.com\r\n\r\n"`

I'm currently struggling to write a function in python that will find all aliases and put them in a list. So basically, I need a list that will be `['alias1.myserver.mysite.com', 'myserver.mysite.com']`

I tried the following code

```
pattern = '(?<=Aliases:  )([\S*]+)'
name =  re.findall(pattern, mystring)
```

but it only matches the first alias and not both of them.

Any ideas on this?

Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import re

s = "Server:  myserver.mysite.com\r\nAddress:  111.122.133.144\r\n\r\nName:    myserver.mysite.com\r\nAddress:  123.144.412.111\r\nAliases:  alias1.myserver.mysite.com\r\n\t  myserver.mysite.com\r\n\r\n"

l = re.findall(r'\S+', s.split('Aliases:  ')[1])
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['alias1.myserver.mysite.com', 'myserver.mysite.com']
```

**Explanation**

First we split the string into two pieces and keep the second piece with `s.split('Aliases:  ')[1]`. This evaluates to the part of the string that follows 'Aliases:  '.

Next we use `findall` with the regaular expression:

```
\S+
```

This matches all consecutive strings of one or more non-space characters.

But this can be more simply done in this case without using a regex:

```
s = "Server:  myserver.mysite.com\r\nAddress:  111.122.133.144\r\n\r\nName:    myserver.mysite.com\r\nAddress:  123.144.412.111\r\nAliases:  alias1.myserver.mysite.com\r\n\t  myserver.mysite.com\r\n\r\n"

l = s.split('Aliases:  ')[1].split()
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'[\n\r\t]')
t="Server:  myserver.mysite.com\r\nAddress:  111.122.133.144\r\n\r\nName:    myserver.mysite.com\r\nAddress:  123.144.412.111\r\nAliases:  alias1.myserver.mysite.com\r\n\t  myserver.mysite.com\r\n\r\n"
t = regex.sub(" ", t)
t = t.split("Aliases:")[1].strip().split()
print(t)
```